# Is i possible to add reactions or edit tags in threads in forums with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that edits every new thread created to keep them organized on the same format, so whenever a new thread is created, it checks if it's on the correct format, and if it's not, it will edit the name to "Request #correct_request_number".

This part works perfectly, but I wanted to know if it's possible to edit the tags, or add reactions in threads, like the setting that allows us to choose a reaction that will be added to every new thread, the point is that I wanted it to add different reactions depending on some conditions like if the thread name was correct or needed to be edited

I tried this to add reactions, but I got an error saying thread does not have the add_reaction attribute

```
@bot.event
async def on_thread_create(thread):
    await thread.add_reaction('✅')
```

Any other method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that a forum thread has no reactions. The reactions that are displayed in the forum menu correspond to those added to the thread's initial message. So, you should use [Thread.starter_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Thread.starter_message) to run your task:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_thread_create(thread):
    await thread.starter_message.add_reaction('✅')
```